# Adding users to a Google calendar in App script

Tags: google-calendar-api

Recently I was working with the App Script and I tried to mass add guests to my Google calendar (not events but the entire calendar) using acl.insert but it gave some error which states that API calls to acl.insert is not found.

I have tried to play around with the access control rule and the authorization scope but they are too complicated for me to understand. How do I mass add guests to a Google calendar? And what are some APIs to mass add users to a Calendar by the owner?

My code is such:

```
function addMemberToCalendar() {
  const calendarId = 'placeholder.com' // the calendar to subscribe
  const subscribers = AdamMemberScripts.getMembers()

  let subscribersArray = [] // array with all members who subscribe to the calendar service
    subscribers.forEach(el => {
      if (el.toggleCalendarSubscription) {
        subscribersArray.push(el.email)
      }
    } 
  )
  const resource = {
      'scope': {
        'type': 'user',
        'value': calendarId
      },
      'role': 'reader'
    };

  for (let i = 0; i < subscribersArray.length; i++) {
    Calendar.Acl.insert(resource, subscribersArray[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code